# How to send emails based on my data. csv file

Tags: powershell

I do a monthly report on inactive accounts and would like to send an email to the managers who are responsible for the service accounts to notify them that the accounts have not been used for more than 30 days based on my data. csv file. When I run my script it only shows one user in the email for each entry in the csv file.

```
$Users = 
@"
Manager;inactiveADAccount
manager_1@domain.com;test_1;test_2;test_3
manager_2@domain.com.ca;test_4
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";"


ForEach($Manager in $Users) {


$bodytxt = @"

Hello,

Please verify users below
$($Manager.inactiveADAccount)

"@


$Message      = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Message.From = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress 'me@domain.com'
$To           = $Manager.Manager
$Object       = "Inactive Accounts"
$body         = $bodytxt
$SMTPServer   = 'mail.domain.com'


Send-MailMessage -From $Message.From -To $To -Subject $Object -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Priority High -Encoding UTF8

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file is not constructed correctly.

See the results of your CSV File:

```
Manager                 inactiveADAccount
-------                 -----------------
manager_1@domain.com    test_1           
manager_2@domain.com.ca test_4
```

As you can see test_2 and test_3 users are omitted from the csv...

Use one row for each user and manager, this should be:

```
$Users = 
@"
Manager;inactiveADAccount
manager_1@domain.com;test_1
manager_1@domain.com;test_2
manager_1@domain.com;test_3
manager_2@domain.com.ca;test_4
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";"
```

Which now includes all the users:

```
Manager                 inactiveADAccount
-------                 -----------------
manager_1@domain.com    test_1           
manager_1@domain.com    test_2           
manager_1@domain.com    test_3           
manager_2@domain.com.ca test_4
```

Then Group The results and send the mail:

```
foreach ($Manager in $Users | group Manager) {

$bodytxt = @"
Hello,

Please verify users below
$($Manager.Group.inactiveADAccount | Out-String) 

"@

[...]
```